# Quais são as regras utilizadas para a fila de análise?

Tags: debate, filas-de-análise

Eu cheguei recentemente aos 500 pontos, e passei a sempre verificar a fila de análise e a responder à alguns usuários que fizeram suas primeiras publicações no site.

Hoje, entretanto, eu vi [esta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/94516/api-velocidade-vias-urbanas) publicada, com dois votos negativos.

<kbd>[image: Pergunta Yoannes]</kbd>

A minha primeira reação, foi de pensar que a pergunta não havia passado pela fila de análise, pela ausência de qualquer comentário.

É claro que, logo em seguida, eu me dei conta de que ela foi provavelmente revisada, mas quem revisou preferiu não deixar um comentário.

**TL;DR - Desculpe por ele estar aqui em baixo ;)**

- *Quais são as regras para que algo vá para as filas de análise?*
- *Nós temos acesso a essas informações?*
- *Só a primeiríssima publicação de um usuário é posta na fila? (Ou a segunda também?)*
- *Existe alguma situação em que a primeira publicação não é colocada na fila?*
- *Se eu, que nunca fiz uma pergunta, fizer agora, eu irei para a fila (mesmo com os meus humildes 500 pontos)?*

Comment: Relacionado: [Como tirar melhor proveito da análise de “Primeiras Publicações”](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1602/3117)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Sobre a pergunta

Sim, ela [foi revisada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/45913) e realmente não houve uma ação efetiva.

Isso geralmente ocorre por falta de atenção ou, em outros casos, porque alguns usuários usam a fila de análise como uma forma de ganhar medalhas ou quem sabe para ter alguma participação note site.

É impossível julgar as razões, mas não é incomum algumas pessoas saírem aprovando tudo sem ao menos deixar uma orientação.

## Eventos da fila de análise

Eu não sei todos os eventos que incluem uma pergunta na fila de análise e as regras que decidem por isso, mas alguns casos comuns são:

- Primeiras perguntas de usuários
- Respostas publicadas muito tempo depois da pergunta
- Edições de usuários com baixa reputação ou usuários não-registrados, evitando vandalismo ou mau uso por pessoas que não conhecem bem o site
- Conteúdo que é identificado como potencialmente de baixa qualidade pelo próprio site, por exemplo, respostas muito pequenas
- Quando algum usuário levanta a flag de baixa qualidade
- Quando há votos para abrir ou suspender uma questão

Você pode ler um pouco mais sobre isso em Inglês [aqui](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/161391/262149).

A própria tela da fila de análise deixa bem claro o motivo da pergunta estar lá, então basta prestar bastante atenção. Claro que existem algumas nuances, tal como edições feita por moderadores ou por usuários de alta reputação.

---

<sup>*PS: Sintam-se à vontade para editar minha resposta e acrescentar mais detalhes.*</sup>

Comment: Não tenho certeza se ao editar uma pergunta fechada, faz diferença se ela está [em-suspenso] ou já [fechada]... Em teoria, nos dois casos isso leva a pergunta para revisão, a confirmar.